# Exponential Equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

How do you find an analytical solution for 3^x-x=4?

Comment: What do you mean by "analytical"?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/ is your friend ;)

Comment: Use the LambertW function.

Answer (score 6):

If you want, you can use [Lambert's W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Let $z:=x+4$, so that the equation becomes $3^{z-4}=z$, so that $-3^{-4}=-z3^{-z}$, which upon inverting with Lambert's $W$ gives:

$x=-\frac{W(-\ln(3)3^{-4})}{\ln(3)}-4$

In particular, $W(r)$ has a nice taylor expansion:

$W(r)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}n^{n-2}}{(n-1)!}r^n$